# Is it possible to recover my HDD

Tags: debian, hard-disk, data-recovery, kubuntu

Recently my PC running Debian crashed and I had to perform hard reboot. Since then I am not able to detect my 500GB Seagate HDD with around 6 partitions. At first it wasn't being detected in BIOS but after disconnecting all other HDDs it started appearing and Debian would display COMRESET (`-errno=16`).

I connected it with an external enclosure and a while ago all partitions were being detected in `dolphin` (but I couldn't mount it), but sadly it doesn't display now.

I tried S.M.A.R.T scan when the drive was displaying and it displayed some read write failure.

Here is `dmesg` output

```
[ 1028.653520] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 312
[ 1028.749540] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1028.749542] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 Sense Key : Aborted Command [current] 
[ 1028.749544] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[ 1028.749546] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 01 39 00 00 07 00
[ 1028.749548] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 313
[ 1028.841491] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1028.841494] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 Sense Key : Aborted Command [current] 
[ 1028.841495] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[ 1028.841498] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 01 50 00 00 01 00
[ 1028.841500] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 336
[ 1028.933527] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1028.933532] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 Sense Key : Aborted Command [current] 
[ 1028.933535] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[ 1028.933538] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 01 51 00 00 07 00
[ 1028.933541] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 337
[ 1029.021544] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1029.021549] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 Sense Key : Aborted Command [current] 
[ 1029.021551] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[ 1029.021555] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 01 80 00 00 01 00
[ 1029.021558] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 384
[ 1029.109517] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1029.109520] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 Sense Key : Aborted Command [current] 
[ 1029.109521] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[ 1029.109523] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 01 81 00 00 07 00
[ 1029.109525] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 385
[ 1029.197498] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1029.197502] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 Sense Key : Aborted Command [current] 
[ 1029.197505] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[ 1029.197508] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 08 f8 00 00 01 00
[ 1029.197511] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 2296
[ 1284.091595] usbcore: deregistering interface driver uas
[ 1348.608075] usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[ 1348.608861] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 1348.608888] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
```

Here is `lsblk` output

```
NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT  sda 8:0 0 465.8G 0 disk
    ├─sda2 8:2 0 464.7G 0 part /media/rockzy/1E01559907F1397D
    └─sda3 8:3 0 998M 0 part

sdb 8:16 0 298.1G 0 disk

    ├─sdb1 8:17 0 68.4G 0 part /media/rockzy/EA420D3D420D0FCD
    ├─sdb2 8:18 0 93.7G 0 part / 
    ├─sdb3 8:19 0 4G 0 part
    ├─sdb4 8:20 0 46.6G 0 part /media/rockzy/267F6D2A48305CDA
    ├─sdb5 8:21 0 2.3G 0 part /boot/efi ├─sdb6 8:22 0 450M 0 part
    ├─sdb7 8:23 0 100M 0 part
    ├─sdb8 8:24 0 16M 0 part
    ├─sdb9 8:25 0 450M 0 part
    ├─sdb10 8:26 0 100M 0 part
    ├─sdb11 8:27 0 450M 0 part
    ├─sdb12 8:28 0 100M 0 part
    └─sdb13 8:29 0 81.6G 0 part /media/rockzy/BCEAB8E2EAB89A5A

sdc 8:32 1 14.9G 0 disk
    └─sdc1 8:33 1 14.9G 0 part /media/rockzy/XUBUNTU 20_

sde 8:64 1 7.5G 0 disk
    └─sde1 8:65 1 7.5G 0 part

sdf 8:80 0 3.9G 0 disK
```

and the `sdf` is my device

I've tried this in Xubuntu Live and moreover HDD is only detected in Linux flavors.

Any help to recover data would be appreciated. I really need to recover data from certain partition and I certainly can't afford data recovery center as I am a student and the drive contains my projects which I have been working for months

Comment: The errors may indicate a hard failure of your disk. You can try to copy the whole disk content to a different disk using tools like `ddrescue` and then try to mount the copy **read-only**. If mounting the copy does not work you can try to recover files with tools like `photorec`. (The next time you should back up your data. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is showing a dead disk.

You might be able to get SMART status but at this stage it's fairly academic. ("*it displayed some read write failure*" is of no use whatsoever. You need to be precise.)

First of all, disconnect the disk and put it somewhere safe. The longer it's powered up the less time you might have left to recover anything at all.

You might be able to use [`ddrescue`](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/) to recover the contents of the disk but by now it's highly unlikely you'll get everything. You'll need a spare disk (or disk partition) that's at least the same size as the partition or disk that you need to recover.

Comment: I had another HDD of same Seagate model and i swapped the boards of it, then I could find all partitions in systemrescuecd and kali Linux live but while I try to read/write it disappears

Comment: It's a dead disk

Comment: hmm.... thanks for your help. am gonna replace it anyways. Could I know what would have caused it to so that I will be preventive next time? because the HDD is only 2 years old and rarely used.

Comment: I don't like guessing. If you had provided the SMART output someone here might have been able to provide a possible diagnosis